# How can i set every street filed on checkout not required? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

Admin configuration is able to set it in range 1-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a plugin etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="rewrite-street" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

It looks like

```
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['authorization-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['validation']
    ['required-entry'] = false;
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['authorization-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['validation']
    ['min_text_length'] = 0;
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

Than you just need to catch the request in Magento\Quote\Model\Quote and set to it custom value or rewrite js/action/**set-payment-information.js** and js/action/**set-shipping-information.js** with the same way. I know this is someway bad, but it is works for me